# Mobile javascript events firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, zepto, hybrid

I am creating a hybrid mobile app using Zepto, backbone, and phonegap and have run into an issue when binding events.  When a click occurs the first time the event is fired once and the page slides out of view, when the page is back in view and a click occurs again the event is fired twice, if you do it a third time the event is fired three times...  Doing an unbind before binding the event doesn't fix it, stopImmediatePropagation also doesn't work.

```
 $('#page-2-view-btn').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert('clicked');
    var view = new PageView2;
    navigator.navigateTo(view);
    return false;
 });
```

Anybody else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
 $('#page-2-view-btn').unbind('click', function(){
    $(this).bind('click', function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        alert('clicked');
        var view = new PageView2;
        navigator.navigateTo(view);
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response but it ends up that the problem was ghost clicks.  The solution can be found https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons or http://labs.ft.com/2011/08/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/